# Retrieving EmbeddedDocument using python and django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have below set of code in models.py in django:

```
class first(EmbeddedDocument):
    var1 = StringField()
    var2 = ListField()

class second(EmbeddedDocument):
    var1 = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(first))
    var2 = StringField()

class main(Document):
    var1 = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(second))
    var2 = StringField()
    other fields
```

From other .py say assign.py: in that I am creating object like

```
obj1 = main.objects.filter(var2=value)
```

Then I am getting values by applying for loop but for embedded data like var1 in main, I am not able to figure out how this data get accessed.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: I Have written below code to access:

```
firstVars = [[[[y.var1, y.var2] for y in x.y], x.var2] for x in obj1.var1]
```

Is there any better approach for accessing such elements. Please let me know.

Comment: You need to show the code of what you've tried.

Comment: I added the EDIT 1, but it is too messy...